# Cannot login to PHPmyAdmin after switching over to HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, phpmyadmin

Thanks to the amazing community here, I was able to get my EC2 instance working over https. For context of this question, please see my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504539/how-can-i-work-around-too-many-redirects-error-when-trying-to-direct-all-web-t/37505299#37505299).

Now, I cannot login to PHPmyAdmin. Even though I load the login screen over https://, I get redirected to `https://mywebsite.co:80/phpmyadmin/index.php`

which shows me the login screen with this error from chrome

`This site can’t provide a secure connection
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I have tried these [solutions](https://thebarton.org/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/) but can't anything to work with my instance.

This looks promising

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule ^/phpmyadmin(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/phpmyadmin$1 [L,R]`

but I can't figure out how to mesh it in with my current configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: You need a secure virtual host `<VirtualHost *:443>` with an ssl certificate.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII my ec2 instance came with a separate file that handles this...I think. It starts with `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>`